# EF Core SplitToTable составного объекта

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Я хочу вынести все цены объекта `Order` в таблицу `OrderPrices`.
Но проблема в том, что цена у меня - составной объект.

```
public class Money
{
    public decimal Amount { get; }
    public string Currency { get; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(
    builder =>
```

В случае, если я настраиваю через Property, я получаю ошибку:

> The 'Money' property 'Order.Amount' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type. Consider converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter.

```
        builder
            .ToTable("Orders")
            .SplitToTable(
                "OrderPrices",
                tableBuilder =>
                {
                    tableBuilder.Property(o=> o.Price);
                    tableBuilder.Property(o=> o.Discount);
                }
```

Я попытался сделать через OwnsOne, но EF Core не поддерживает такое и просто отказывается компилировать.

```
        builder
            .ToTable("Orders")
            .SplitToTable(
                "OrderPrices",
                tableBuilder =>
                {
                    tableBuilder.OwnsOne(b => b.Price, builder =>
                    {
                        builder.Property(b => b.Amount).IsRequired();
                        builder.Property(b => b.Currency).HasMaxLength(3).IsRequired();
                    });
                    tableBuilder.OwnsOne(b => b.Discount, builder =>
                    {
                        builder.Property(b => b.Amount).IsRequired();
                        builder.Property(b => b.Currency).HasMaxLength(3).IsRequired();
                    });
                }
```

Возможно, можно сделать JsonConverter и хранить `Money` в виде JSON. Но хотелось бы, чтобы к столбцам с ценой можно было писать нормальные SQL-запросы.

Comment: Рис - цена 100р, Телефон - цена 50$, Пакет молока - цена 100р. Вот вам условные товары с их ценой, где цена у вас "составной объект", ок. Как вы представляете себе хранение этого в базе? Вот вы хотите вынести цены в отдельную таблицу, ок, будет таблица с данными `100 рублей`, `100 рублей`, `50 долларов`. что из этого ключ? Хорошо, цена риса 100р, какие из добавленных в базу `100р` нужно взять для конкретного риса? Поняли к чему я клоню? если вы хотите вынести цены (что странно) в отдельную таблицу, дайте значит объекту цены уникальный ID, который EF подставит в таблицу товара.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ
Но SplitToTable должен сам создать связи, как и OwnsOne.ToTable. Я же хочу вынести их в другую таблицу чтобы снизить нагрузку на основную при update.

Comment: @vusaldev Это не отменяет того факта, что должен быть у каждой сущности уникальный ключ. Повторю: Рис стоит 100р, какой объект из двух должен быть вытянут из таблицы в этом случае? Первый или второй? Почти все базы, их разделение, и прочее работает по ID, то есть `Id: 1, Name: "Вася", Age: 46, Company: 1`, внимание на `Company`, тут цифра, которая ссылается на другую таблицу, таблицу компаний, где есть `Id: 1, Name: "Супер компания", Address: "Адрес компании"`. Ну и повторю, очень странно выносить данные конкретного товара в отдельную таблицу. вы так не разгружаете ничего.